# Oracle function perform better than inline query

Tags: oracle, performance, function, compare, subquery

I have one long query which have a lot of let join with subqueries. It 's have some performance issue. I have just put subqueries inside new function and the function execute that subqueries and store the output in a collection (user defined table  which contain user defined object). when I execute outer query with this function it's perform better than subqueries but we don't found the answer why it's happend.

Example : Existing Query

```
select * 
from a 
   left join (select * from b left join c on b.something =c.something where b.something=`something`) d on a.something = d.something
```

Update the query

```
create object user_obj as ( column_name varchar, column_name varchar);
create or replace TYPE table_name AS TABLE OF user_obj; 
create function test (something) as 
 report  table_name := table_name();
Begin
   for i in (select * from b left join c on b.something =c.something where 
    b.something='something')loop
    report.EXTEND;
    report(report.count) := (user_obj(i.firstcolumnvalue, 
          i.secondColumnValue))
    end loop;
       return report;
End
```

calling function by outer query

```
select * from a left join (select * from table(test(input_data))) d on a.something = d.something
```

When I executing through function it's give me better performance as compare to inline query

I want a reason why performance is better in function

Comment: What are the execution plans for the two queries?

Comment: It should be even faster if you run `select user_obj(firstcolumnvalue, secondColumnValue) BULK COLLECT INO report from b left join c on b.something =c.something where b.something='test')` or a [Pipelined](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14289/dcitblfns.htm) function instead of one-by-one in a loop.

Comment: thanks Wernfried Domscheit for early replying. I want to know that why function performs better than inline query. without function inline query it takes 3 sec to execute but when I put subquery in the function and execute. it takes only 0.45 s sec

Comment: Anecdotes aren't evidence. You need to include explain plans and runtime stats for the two statements. If you have a user with the PLUSTRACE role you can get some helpful info using the SQL\*Plus AUTOTRACE option. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96533/autotrac.htm)